# What is close combat in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, military, weapons

I checked a couple of dictionaries, but I found no translation for "close combat".
I am looking for an expression for fighting close to one's enemy as opposed to using long distance weaponry.
What would be a good translation for "close combat" in Latin?
How did the Romans describe fighting without long range weapons?
*Pugna proxima* is my best attempt, but it sounds wrong.

The example sentence I have in mind is "A sword is a weapon for close combat".
(Pick any of the words for a sword you like.)

Comment: It was interesting re-reading the etymology of mêlée, and learning that its Latin origin (mêlée < meslee ≡ medley < medlee (variant of meslee); meslee < *misculāre) suggests how chaotic battle mêlée presumably was – quite far removed from the macro-level skirmish or battle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Vergil uses a great adverb to convey the idea of being "at close quarters": [*comminus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcomminus).

> Tum contra Iuno; “Terrorum et fraudis abunde est;
>   stant belli causae, **pugnatur comminus armis**,
>   quae fors prima dedit sanguis novus imbuit arma..." (Vir. *Aen* 7.552-554)

Some more examples from other authors:

- with *pugnare*

> dum locus **comminus pugnandi** daretur... (Caes. B. C. 1, 58)

- with *utor* + ablative (here *comminus* is contrasted with its opposite, *eminus*):

> nec eminus hastis aut **comminus gladiis** uteretur (Cic. Sen. 6, 19)

- with other verbs (approaching closer to your example sentence):

> ...gladio **comminus geri** rem... (Liv. 44, 35, 12)

Using these examples as a model, I would translate *A sword is a weapon for close combat* as:

> **Gladium instrumentum est comminus pugnandi**

(I'm not too happy with *instrumentum* here, but I am having trouble thinking of a generic word for *weapon* besides *telum*, which for me implies distance, and *arma*, which I believe only works in the plural.)

Comment: I had never heard of *comminus* before, but it looks very suitable for my purpose. I'm sure I can figure out a way to use it to express what I want.

Comment: Hmm. The problem is that in the Roman period almost all combat was up close and personal. It's the norm, whereas fighting via the available distance weapons was not even considered to be *combat*.

Comment: @andy256, I can get on board with that, but I'm not sure how that bears on the current question, which has to do with explicitly stating that a conflict/weapon is for close combat. Romans also had projectiles, and the quote from Cicero demonstrates that there certainly is an explicit distinction to be made.

Comment: @andy256, and now that I think of it, I strongly disagree that projectile fighting was not considered combat: consider Achilles vs Hector or Aeneas vs Turnus, who each began their duels with spear-throwing. This was undoubtedly a big part of their *combat*.

Comment: @brianpck You make telling points!

Answer (score 8):

Smith's *Introduction to Latin Prose Composition* gives the following distinctions:

> **Prœlium, i**, an engagement, action, or skirmish. **Pugna, æ**, generally a close engagement, but often in a general sense for any kind of contest or battle. **Acies, ei** generally a pitched battle, properly the first line of an army, resembling the edge of an instrument.

In which case *pugna* is exactly what you want, which sort of makes sense—any engagement with the fist (*pugna*) has to be close.